# Create Athena table with Json

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have done a lab question that requires me to find a string of text from logs which I have done so by the long way (excel) instead of the intelligent way (having data populated nicely on the table in Athena). I have multiple files within an S3 folder that has json format like this...

```json
{"Records":[{"eventVersion":"1.05","userIdentity":{"type":"AssumedRole","principalId":"ARXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFVEC:AWSConfig-Describe","arn":"arn:aws:sts::2CCCCCCCCC8:assumed-role/AWSServiceRoleForConfig/AWSConfig-Describe","accountId":"2CCCCCCCCC8","accessKeyId":"ASXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXQVL","sessionContext":{"sessionIssuer":{"type":"Role","principalId":"ARXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFVEC","arn":"arn:aws:iam::2CCCCCCCCC8:role/aws-service-role/config.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForConfig","accountId":"2CCCCCCCCC8","userName":"AWSServiceRoleForConfig"},"attributes":{"creationDate":"2019-09-03T07:40:00Z","mfaAuthenticated":"false"}},"invokedBy":"AWS Internal"},"eventTime":"2019-09-03T07:40:00Z","eventSource":"s3.amazonaws.com","eventName":"HeadBucket","awsRegion":"us-west-2","sourceIPAddress":"172.18.87.252","userAgent":"[AWSConfig]","requestParameters":{"bucketName":"service_logs_10l51wolgib72","Host":"s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"},"responseElements":null,"additionalEventData":{"SignatureVersion":"SigV4","CipherSuite":"ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA","bytesTransferredIn":0.0,"AuthenticationMethod":"AuthHeader","x-amz-id-2":"JYEwSk6jEv2rB/MjwluNXcnKxRSo72GCOz8WP9OYXDFI2FxS1T81K7excoDuo36rJIQz9MWYKEE=","bytesTransferredOut":0.0},"requestID":"E224F90BD7370007","eventID":"77d7ea03-b8a2-4b50-8f81-b8217eacf008","readOnly":true,"resources":[{"type":"AWS::S3::Object","ARNPrefix":"arn:aws:s3:::service_logs_10l51wolgib72/"},{"accountId":"2CCCCCCCCC8","type":"AWS::S3::Bucket","ARN":"arn:aws:s3:::service_logs_10l51wolgib72"}],"eventType":"AwsApiCall","recipientAccountId":"2CCCCCCCCC8","vpcEndpointId":"vpce-3c0ee766"},{"eventVersion":"1.05","userIdentity":{"type":"AssumedRole","principalId":"ARXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFVEC:AWSConfig-Describe","arn":"arn:aws:sts::2CCCCCCCCC8:assumed-role/AWSServiceRoleForConfig/AWSConfig-Describe","accountId":"2CCCCCCCCC8","accessKeyId":"ASXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXQVL","sessionContext":{"sessionIssuer":{"type":"Role","principalId":"ARXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFVEC","arn":"arn:aws:iam::2CCCCCCCCC8:role/aws-service-role/config.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForConfig","accountId":"2CCCCCCCCC8","userName":"AWSServiceRoleForConfig"},"attributes":{"creationDate":"2019-09-03T07:40:00Z","mfaAuthenticated":"false"}},"invokedBy":"AWS Internal"},"eventTime":"2019-09-03T07:40:00Z","eventSource":"s3.amazonaws.com","eventName":"HeadBucket","awsRegion":"us-west-2","sourceIPAddress":"172.18.87.252","userAgent":"[AWSConfig]","requestParameters":{"bucketName":"service_logs_10l51wolgib72","Host":"s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"},"responseElements":null,"additionalEventData":{"SignatureVersion":"SigV4","CipherSuite":"ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA","bytesTransferredIn":0.0,"AuthenticationMethod":"AuthHeader","x-amz-id-2":"JYEwSk6jEv2rB/MjwluNXcnKxRSo72GCOz8WP9OYXDFI2FxS1T81K7excoDuo36rJIQz9MWYKEE=","bytesTransferredOut":0.0},"requestID":"E224F90BD7370020","eventID":"77d7ea03-b8a2-4b50-8f81-b8217eacf021","readOnly":true,"resources":[{"type":"AWS::S3::Object","ARNPrefix":"arn:aws:s3:::service_logs_10l51wolgib72/"},{"accountId":"2CCCCCCCCC8","type":"AWS::S3::Bucket","ARN":"arn:aws:s3:::service_logs_10l51wolgib72"}],"eventType":"AwsApiCall","recipientAccountId":"2CCCCCCCCC8","vpcEndpointId":"vpce-3c0ee766"},{"eventVersion":"1.05","userIdentity":{"type":"AssumedRole","principalId":"ARXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFVEC:AWSConfig-Describe","arn":"arn:aws:sts::2CCCCCCCCC8:assumed-role/AWSServiceRoleForConfig/AWSConfig-Describe","accountId":"2CCCCCCCCC8","accessKeyId":"ASXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXQVL","sessionContext":{"sessionIssuer":{"type":"Role","principalId":"ARXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXFVEC","arn":"arn:aws:iam::2CCCCCCCCC8:role/aws-service-role/config.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForConfig","accountId":"2CCCCCCCCC8","userName":"AWSServiceRoleForConfig"},"attributes":{"creationDate":"2019-09-03T07:40:00Z","mfaAuthenticated":"false"}},"invokedBy":"AWS Internal"},"eventTime":"2019-09-03T07:40:00Z","eventSource":"s3.amazonaws.com","eventName":"HeadBucket","awsRegion":"us-west-2","sourceIPAddress":"172.18.87.252","userAgent":"[AWSConfig]","requestParameters":{"bucketName":"service_logs_10l51wolgib72","Host":"s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"},"responseElements":null,"additionalEventData":{"SignatureVersion":"SigV4","CipherSuite":"ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA","bytesTransferredIn":0.0,"AuthenticationMethod":"AuthHeader","x-amz-id-2":"JYEwSk6jEv2rB/MjwluNXcnKxRSo72GCOz8WP9OYXDFI2FxS1T81K7excoDuo36rJIQz9MWYKEE=","bytesTransferredOut":0.0},"requestID":"E224F90BD7370033","eventID":"77d7ea03-b8a2-4b50-8f81-b8217eacf034","readOnly":true,"resources":[{"type":"AWS::S3::Object","ARNPrefix":"arn:aws:s3:::service_logs_10l51wolgib72/"},{"accountId":"2CCCCCCCCC8","type":"AWS::S3::Bucket","ARN":"arn:aws:s3:::service_logs_10l51wolgib72"}],"eventType":"AwsApiCall","recipientAccountId":"2CCCCCCCCC8","vpcEndpointId":"vpce-3c0ee766"}]}
```

I am importing them (the whole dir with the files sharing same format) into Athena using this code from online reference but no matter how I adjust, I still get the table with single column...

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `default`.testjson4 (
 Records struct<eventVersion:string,
             userIdentity:string,
             eventTime:string,
             eventSource:string>)

ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'ignore.malformed.json' = 'FALSE',
  'dots.in.keys' = 'FALSE',
  'case.insensitive' = 'TRUE',
  'mapping' = 'TRUE'
)
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://******************/CloudTrail/us-east-1/****/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('classification' = 'json');
```

Would like to get help on how to do this correctly, thank you!